# Read first line from file and access this path

Tags: c

I'm writing a code that **reads the first line from a file**, where this line includes a path to directory. Then the `list_dir()` function would enter all subfolders..
I checked the `list_dir()` and it's works great when I'm sending the path manually - 
For example: `list_dir ("/home/Desktop/example");`

Here is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <dirent.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <dirent.h>
#include <limits.h>

static void list_dir (const char *dirPath)
{
    // Open the directory in dir_name
    DIR *d;
    d = opendir (dirPath);
    /* Check it was opened. */
    printf("%s",dirPath);
    if (!d) {
        printf ("Cannot open directory\n");
        exit (1);
    }

    while (1) {
        struct dirent * entry;
        const char * d_name;

        /* "Readdir" gets subsequent entries from "d". */
        entry = readdir (d);
        /* if There are no more entries in this directory */
        if (!entry) {
            break;
        }

        /* Print the name of the file and directory. */
        d_name = entry->d_name;
        printf ("%s/%s\n", dirPath, d_name);

        if (entry->d_type & DT_DIR) {
            /* Check that the directory is not "d" or d's parent. */
            if (strcmp (d_name, "..") != 0 && strcmp (d_name, ".") != 0) {
                int path_length;
                char path[PATH_MAX];
                path_length = snprintf (path, PATH_MAX,"%s/%s", dirPath, d_name);
                printf ("%s\n", path);
                if (path_length >= PATH_MAX) {
                    fprintf (stderr, "Path length has got too long.\n");
                    exit (EXIT_FAILURE);
                }
                /* Recursively call "list_dir" with the new path. */
                list_dir(path);
            }
        }
    }

    /* After going through all the entries, close the directory. */
    if (closedir (d)) {
        printf ("Cannot Close directory");
        exit (1);
    }
}


void main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    //configuration file path
    char* dirPath = argv[1];

    FILE *f1 = fopen(dirPath, "r");
    if (f1 == NULL) {
        printf("Cannot open the file for reading");
        exit(1);
    }

    char *line = NULL;
    size_t len = 0;
    ssize_t read;

    while ((read = getline(&line, &len, f1)) != -1) {
        break;
    }

    list_dir (line);
    fclose (f1);
    free(line);
}
```

example for the txt file:

```
/home/Desktop/example/
bla bla bla
bla bla bla
```

As you understand, the problem is when I'm sending the path from `main()` function, `list_dir()` can't open the path and I get `"Cannot open directory"` as an error. Help?

Comment: code is ever so much easier to read/understand if a couple of rules are followed.  1) never use tabs for indenting code  2) indent after each opening brace '{' un-indent before each closing brace '}'.  3) insert a blank line between each code block.

Comment: please post code that (as it stands) compiles ( unless asking about a compile error) missing #include statements, etc means the code will not compile.

Comment: regarding this line: 'void main(int argc, char *argv[])'  the compiler will raise two warnings about unused parameter 'argc' and parameter 'argv[]'  Suggest enabling all compiler warnings when compiling, then fix the warnings, then re-post a compilable version of the code.

Comment: @user3121023 do you have an idea how to remove it?

Comment: Note that if there is no first line in the file (so `getline()` returns -1), you will go ahead and try to process the directory that is specified by the null pointer, which will (almost certainly) lead to a crash and certainly won't do what you want.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As the commenters above said there is a newline at the end of `dirPath` and that's why you get `Cannot open directory`, add `strtok(dirPath, "\n");` just before `opendir` to get rid of the trailing newline.

Also note that you are including some headers more than once and that main should return an int.